# How to give more than one role for an object in java?

Tags: java

the student and teacher class inherited from person class, because inheritance is not flexible the object will either be one of the two. to solve this i added an abstract class Role and make association between person and role and student and teacher inherits from Role class so that an instance can has a role of both student and teacher.The question is to make instance of the Teacher class can also be a student or a student also teaches how to test in the main class?

[image: class Diagram]

```java
public class Person {

    private int ssn;
    private String name;
    private List<PersonRole> roles;

    public Person(int ssn, String name) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
        this.name = name;
        roles = new ArrayList<PersonRole>();
    }

    public int getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
   }

/////////////// PersonRole /////////////////

public abstract class PersonRole {
    private List<PersonRole> learning;
    private List<PersonRole> teaching;

    public PersonRole(List<PersonRole> learning, List<PersonRole> teaching) {
        this.learning = learning;
        this.teaching = teaching;
    }
     public List<PersonRole> getLearning() {
        return learning;
    }
    public List<PersonRole> getTeaching() {
        return teaching;
    }
    
    public void addAsStudent(PersonRole p) {
        learning.add(p);
    }
    public void addAsTeacher(PersonRole p) {
        learning.add(p);
    }
    }

/////////////  Teacher //////////////

public class Teacher extends PersonRole {

    private String faultyName;
    private int yearsOfExperence;

    public Teacher(String faultyName, int yearsOfExperence) {
        super();
        this.faultyName = faultyName;
        this.yearsOfExperence = yearsOfExperence;
    }

    public String getFaultyName() {
        return faultyName;
    }

    public int getYearsOfExperence() {
        return yearsOfExperence;
    }

}

///////////  Student  ////////////////

public class Student extends PersonRole {

    private String collegeName;
    private String major;

    public Student(String collegeName, String major) {
        super();
        this.collegeName = collegeName;
        this.major = major;
    }

    public String getCollegeName() {
        return collegeName;
    }

    public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }

}


////// Main ///////////////

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonRole p1 = new Student("univ of Michigan", "CS");
        PersonRole p3 = new Student("Iowa state univ", "managemnt");
        PersonRole p2 = new Teacher("computer science", 3);
        PersonRole p4 = new Teacher("Management", 2);

        Person person = new Person(1042327867, "Mike Rose");

        person.addRole(p1);
        person.addRole(p2);
        person.addRole(p3);
        person.addRole(p4);

        for (PersonRole c: roles) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would test it exactly as you would but the hierarchy of inheritance looks good. Why not give PersonRole a constructor and attributes so that the children can use super() in their constructors and reuse some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to print your roles:

```
List<PersonRole> roles = person.getRole();
for(PersonRole role: roles) {
    System.out.println(role);
}
```

Then add a toString method in the Student and Teacher classes:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Student {" + "collegeName=" + collegeName + ", major=" + major + '}';
}
```

```
public String toString() {
    return "Teacher {" + "faultyName=" + faultyName + ", yearsOfExperence=" + yearsOfExperence + '}';
}
```

The result will be this:

```
Student {collegeName=maharashi univ, major=compro}
Teacher {faultyName=computer science, yearsOfExperence=3}
Student {collegeName=Iowa state univ, major=managemnt}
Teacher {faultyName=Management, yearsOfExperence=2}
```